# How to create randomly colored text in Trinket.io/Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am making a game called Gravity code, where the objective of the game is to catch falling items that change the color, speed, size, or shape of the turtle. Where I need a randomly colored title.

```
# --- imports ---

import turtle
from random import * 

# --- variables ---

font_setup = ("Verdana", 25, "normal")
screen = turtle.Screen()

# --- main ---

title.speed("fastest")
title.hideturtle()
title.penup()
title.goto(-62, 60)
title.write("Gravity", font = font_setup)
title.setpos(-45, 30)
title.write("Code", font = font_setup)

# --- events ---

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: use [turtle.onclick](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick()) or `turtle.onscreenclick` to execute function when you click and check if mouse position is inside button's rectangle.

Comment: "trinket python"? you mean tkinter?

Comment: @Tibebes.M it can be portal [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/console)

Comment: @furas ohh my bad. I had no clue of the platform, thanks

Comment: @Tibebes.M long time ago there was similar [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python_turtle) but it seem now you have to create account

Comment: you could keep button position as `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`. you can use `onscreenclick` to run function when you click mouse - and this function should get mouse position so you can check it with button position - `x1 < mouse_x < x2 and y1 < mouse_y < y2`. Eventually you can try if will work `button.click(1, function)` to execute function when you click your `button`

Comment: I use Turtle only to draw figures like in [this gallery](https://blog.furas.pl/rysowanie-w-turtle-galeria-rysunkow.html) and I wasn't sure how `onclick` works. Normally I would use `PyGame` which uses rectangle to draw button and it keeps this rectangle as two corners - `left, top` (`x1,y1`) and `right, bottom` (`x2, y2`) and then you check `(left < mouse_x < right) and (top < mouse_y < bottom)`

Comment: @Tibebes.M thank you, `turtle` is nice for drawing figures - but not for games :) In subpages I have code for every image in this gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `turtle.onclick(function, mouse_button)` to execute function when you click your `button`.

`onclick` needs only function's name without `()` (so called "callback")

`on_button_click` has to get two values - mouse position.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def on_button_click(x, y):
    print('button clicked:', x,y)
    button.hideturtle()
    
# --- main ---
    
screen = turtle.Screen()
button = turtle.Turtle()

button.speed("fastest")
#screen.addshape("icons8-button-100.png") #It's the second button.
#button.shape("icons8-button-100.png") #https://icons8.com/icons/set/button
button.left(90) # The second image is the button I'm using.
button.penup() #It can be resized afer you click download to...
button.goto(0, -120) # 70 x 70 pixels.

button.onclick(on_button_click, 1)

screen.mainloop()
```